# Implement a custom StaggereGrid in UIView like Etsy app in SWIFT

Tags: swift, ios8, libraries, staggered-gridview, etsy

I want to implement a StaggeredGrid like Etsy app, but i have no idea about it.

Can you give me any advices to do that?

this is an screenshot of what i need to do:

[image: StaggeredGrid Screenshot]

Comment: I think you need to look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html

Comment: You want a `UICollectionView` with a custom layout - this one looks promising: https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout

Comment: ty @Nate Cook, it's the best way before self-custom an UICollectionView without useless error :D