# Is there a way to make layout like Android StaggeredGridView using react-native in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, staggeredgridlayout

Android StaggeredGridLayout allows you to layout cards in columns with different height, like how Pinterest does. Is this possible using React-native on iOS?

Comment: Not sure about reactive, but you can surely achieve that layout using `UICollectionView` and a (customized) flow layout. Not gonna be quick and easy, though.

Comment: Check out this question and the links in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26717561/433373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible.
Have a look at https://github.com/xudafeng/autoresponsive_react_native_sample

[image: pinterest like layout]

Comment: awesome, this covers both Android and iOS!