# How to create Unsplash like Grid System?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

The grid in [Unsplash](http://unsplash.com) is a bit different.
Some levels are up & some are down. I can't seem to figure out it can be done with flexbox.

[image: Unsplash Image]

So my question is how to create this grid using Flexbox or plain CSS & i know it might require some JavaScript for random grid sizes ?
Answer in React Native is preferrable

Comment: seems like it refers to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004529/is-there-a-way-to-make-layout-like-android-staggeredgridview-using-react-native

Comment: Thanx man. I'm gonna take a look at it & try & see if it works for me which I think it should & I will give an update later tonight 

Comment: no problem @Akshay Kadam, keep up

Comment: Great, its working with a little bit of tweaking !! Thanks 

Comment: nice, glad to hear that